# How to redirect WordPress URL to base url without parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We are trying to redirect URL like `http://example.com/gtsdsds8yz/x3idsdssq.php?wtb=hgtvsdsd-m3u` To `http://example.com`

for that, we are using `.htaccess` like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^wtb=hgtvsdsd-m3u$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*
RewriteRule ^gtsdsds8yz/x3idsdssq\.php https://example.com [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: so If I understand it correctly, you have wordpress instance on a sub-directory but you want URL to be pointed without that directory in URL?

Comment: yes, but currently we removed that folder so we are planing 301 redirects to home page @FaisalSarfraz

Comment: You've not stated what the problem is with your current directives? Do you get an error? Incorrect redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^wtb=hgtvsdsd-m3u$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*
> RewriteRule ^gtsdsds8yz/x3idsdssq\.php https://example.com [L,R=301]
> ```

This should redirect to the root, however, it won't strip the URL parameters, which I assume is your problem? But note that you are strictly missing the trailing slash after the hostname on the substitution string (the *browser* would need to correct this).

To remove the query string you need the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag (Apache 2.4+). Or, if you are still on Apache 2.2 then append a `?` to the end of the *substitution* string instead.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^wtb=hgtvsdsd-m3u$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^gtsdsds8yz/x3idsdssq\.php https://example.com/ [L,R=301,QSD]
```

Note that this should go *before* all the WordPress directives, at the top of your `.htaccess` file.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> ```

You have also placed your HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the wrong place. This needs to go at the start of the file as well - before the WordPress front-controller as it simply won't redirect your WP URLs.